# How I Can redirect the domain to my public IPAddress on ESP?

Tags: arduino, wifi, ip-address, esp8266, esp32

I have the next problem:

I am programing on Arduino to ESP32 and I use the IPAddress to connect my server with public IP.
The X.X.X.X represents my IP.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h> 

IPAddress server_addr(X,X,X,X);   // IP DE SQL
```

The code of the top works fine!
I wish push in the code my public domain like: example.domain.com

```
IPAddress server_addr(example.domain.com);
```

I did the redirect from my webhosting, but I don´t know how put this domain on my code.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: as `const char* server = "example.domain.com"`

Comment: Hi Juraj, I tried this sentence, but how I can connect to IPAddress?
I tried something like this :
`code` IPAddress server_addr(server); `code`
But doesn´t work (Error compiling: no matching function for call to 'IPAddress(const char*&)'
)

Comment: connect has a version for host name `connect(server, port);`